# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject into Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject issues

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I am working on a C# project.

```
[
  {"FirstName":"XYZ","LastName":"SSS"},
  {"FirstName":"ABC","LastName":"NNN"}
]
```

Each row represents an object of class ChildDTO.

I read the above data from the file and am trying to deserialize into a ParentCollection object like below:

```
string file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Children_CA.txt");
ParentCollection pCollection = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParentCollection>(file);
```

My DTO classes are like below:

```
[Serializable]
public class ParentCollection : CollectionBase
{    
  public void Add(ChildDTO dto)
  {
      //List is from Systems.Collections.CollectionBase class
      List.Add(dto);
  }
}

[Serializable]
public class ChildDTO
{
   // properties like FirstName and LastName goes here
}
```

**I cannot change my DTO classes since they are old and already in production from the past 20 years and many applications are using them.**

**When I see Quick Watch on pCollection, I notice the collection is having objects of type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. I am hoping to have objects of type ChildDTO**

[image]

Please let me know what mistake I am doing.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights... Thanks for edits...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `CollectionBase`, and by extension your `ParentCollection` class, are not generic, so Json.Net doesn't know that the items in the collection are supposed to be `ChildDTO` objects.  Since it doesn't know what type the items are, it just uses `JObject` instead.  You can fix the problem using a custom `JsonConverter` class like this:

```
class ParentCollectionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(ParentCollection);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ParentCollection pc = new ParentCollection();
        JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);
        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            pc.Add(item.ToObject<ChildDTO>());
        }
        return pc;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, pass it to `DeserializeObject<T>` like this:

```
ParentCollection pCollection = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParentCollection>(json, new ParentCollectionConverter());
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3GM22c

Comment: Wow worked like a charm. Now my ParentCollection is working without any errors. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning. If you need the ChildDto's list, please convert it to List. Please refer to the code and image below. Many thanks.

```
            string file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Children_CA.txt");
            var results1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChildDTO>>(file);
```

[image: Code with output Image]

Comment: I need to Deserialize into ParentCollection. Thanks for your help.